# Slider Toggle on Android 4.4.2

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I'm actually using PhoneGap with Jquery mobile in order to develop a mobile app but i have a problem with a `<select data-role="slider">`.
It works fine on Android 4.3, IOS 7 and Google Chrome but not in Android 4.4.2.
When i create the slider it works fine when I slide it, the text and color disappears.

The demo slider :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="flip-b">Flip switch:</label>
            <select name="slider" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            </select> 
</div>
```